# Replace placeholders in order

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a part of a URL like this:

```
/home/{value1}/something/{anotherValue}
```

Now i want to replace all between the brackets with values from a string-array.

I tried this RegEx pattern: `\{[a-zA-Z_]\}` but it doesn't work.

Later (in C#) I want to replace the first match with the first value of the array, second with the second.

Update: The /'s cant be used to separate. Only the placeholders {...} should be replaced.

Example: /home/before{value1}/and/{anotherValue}

String array: {"Tag", "1"}

Result: /home/beforeTag/and/1

I hoped it could works like this:

```
string input = @"/home/before{value1}/and/{anotherValue}";
string pattern = @"\{[a-zA-Z_]\}";
string[] values = {"Tag", "1"};

MatchCollection mc = Regex.Match(input, pattern);        
for(int i, ...)
{
    mc.Replace(values[i];
}        
string result = mc.GetResult;
```

Edit:
Thank you Devendra D. Chavan and ipr101,

both solutions are greate!

Comment: why regexp? Can't you just split the string on delimeter `/` and use index 1 and 3?

Comment: Do you have a code sample and a "before" and "after" string to make the question somewhat clearer?

Comment: Using the pattern, `{[a-zA-Z0-1]*}` or `{\w*}` in your example would give the desired result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this code fragment,

```
// Begin with '{' followed by any number of word like characters and then end with '}'
var pattern = @"{\w*}"; 
var regex = new Regex(pattern);

var replacementArray = new [] {"abc", "cde", "def"};
var sourceString = @"/home/{value1}/something/{anotherValue}";

var matchCollection = regex.Matches(sourceString);
for (int i = 0; i < matchCollection.Count && i < replacementArray.Length; i++)
{
    sourceString = sourceString.Replace(matchCollection[i].Value, replacementArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: `{` is a quantifier delimiter, you should escape it as in the question with `\{` and `\}`.

Comment: Not really required in this case ([Regex reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html)), but can be added for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

`[a-zA-Z_]` describes a character class. For words, you'll have to add `*` at the end (any number of characters within `a-zA-Z_`.

Then, to have 'value1' captured, you'll need to add number support : `[a-zA-Z0-9_]*`, which can be summarized with: `\w*`

So try this one : `{\w*}`

But for replacing in C#, string.Split('/') might be easier as Fredrik proposed. [Have a look at this too](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a delegate, something like this -

```
string[] strings = {"dog", "cat"};
int counter = -1;
string input = @"/home/{value1}/something/{anotherValue}";
Regex reg = new Regex(@"\{([a-zA-Z0-9]*)\}");
string result = reg.Replace(input, delegate(Match m) {
    counter++;
    return "{" + strings[counter] + "}";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My two cents:

```
// input string     
string txt = "/home/{value1}/something/{anotherValue}";

// template replacements
string[] str_array = { "one", "two" };

// regex to match a template
Regex regex = new Regex("{[^}]*}");

// replace the first template occurrence for each element in array
foreach (string s in str_array)
{
    txt = regex.Replace(txt, s, 1);
}

Console.Write(txt);
```